# What is the new "mountains" in the progress bar of YouTube?

Tags: youtube

What does the "mountain" overlay when hovering the cursor over the time/progress bar mean?

Hovering over progress bar:

[image: hover]

Normal video playing:

[image: normal]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hover the cursor over the highest peak of the "moutains", it will say "most viewed". This implies that the "mountains" mean how many viewers have watched that section

[image: hover-peak]